# SSIS Execute SQL Query error with DateTime Input Parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have spent a few days trying to fix this problem.  I have a SSIS package with 2 execute SQL tasks within a sequence container, one is a simple delete from table and the next one an simple insert the delete precedes the insert. The delete works fine so the connection etc is ok.

The Insert is failing with the following vague and unhelpful message.

```
failed with the following error: "Syntax error, permission violation, or other nonspecific error". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

The insert has 1 input parameter which is a date which is bound to a datetime variable set to 01/01/2011.  When I replace the ? in the sql task query with a hard coded date the task works. I have also looked at the locals at a pre-execute event break point on the insert task and the variable is ok.

I also fired up a SQL Profiler session and I see the delete query hitting the DB but nothing for the insert (when it uses the input parameter).

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Pro SP1 (Not my choice) and SQL Server 2005 SP3.

Regards

Mark

Comment: Is the SQL connection OLE DB, ODBC or something else?

Answer (score 6):

I know that you have found an answer to your question. However, I would like to clarify here that the following query you were executing using **OleDb** connection is valid and it does work within the `Execute SQL Task` in `SSIS` package.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (DateCol, OtherCol, OtherCol1) 
SELECT ?, SourceCol1, SourceCol2 FROM dbo.SourceTable
```

Following example shows a successful implementation of the above mentioned query using **SSIS 2005** (`Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) 2005`)

**Step-by-step process:**

1. Create two tables named `dbo.Source` and `dbo.Destination` using the scripts provided under the **Scripts** section. Populate the table `dbo.Source` with data as shown in screenshot #**1**. Table `dbo.Destination` will initially be empty and will be populated with source data using an Execute SQL Task.
2. On the SSIS package, create an OLE DB Connection named **SQLServer** in the `Connections Managers` pointing to a SQL Server instance of your preference. Refer screenshot #**2**.
3. On the SSIS package, create a variable named **RecordDate** as shown in screenshot #**3**.
4. On the SSIS package, place an `Execute SQL Task` as shown in screenshot #**4**. Configure the task as shown in screenshots #**5** and #**6**.
5. Screenshot #**7** shows sample package execution.
6. Screenshot #**8** shows data in the tables `dbo.Source` and `dbo.Destination` after package execution.

Hope that helps.

**Scripts:**
.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destination](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateValue] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Destination] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Source](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Source] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your SQL Statement is of the correct type to be parameterized according to your connection manager.

If you're using OLE DB - your Insert statement needs to be of some kind like `INSERT INTO Tbl(col) VALUES (?)`

Resultset should be "None" (As there's nothing to return on your INSERT), and the Parameter Mapping tab should have a single parameter (or as many as ?'s you have, and Parameter Name should (for OLE DB) start on 0, then 1, 2 ... ,n. If you were using an ADO connection you would have to name the parameters Param1, Param2, ... ParamN.

You can see the reference for passing variables to the respective connection managers here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502.aspx

**Proper answer as per your comment**:
You cannot use a parameter mapping in a query of that kind. But there is an easy way to do it.

Make a new variable sqlCommand (type string). click it in the list of variables, and press F4 to see properties. Change "EvaluateAsExpression" to true, and click the expression box to get up the expression window. In here make your query in a format like this `"INSERT INTO tbl(dateCol,intCol,charCol) SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + (DT_STR,20,1252)@[User::dateVar] + "',104) AS dateCol, intCol, charCol from anotherTbl"`

When you click Evaluate Expression you'll see a valid SQL statement being formed that you can use.

Now go back to the Execute SQL task, remove the parameter mapping. Close the dialog box, click the Execute SQL task, press F4, find the expressions line, click the ... and add an expression on the Property "SqlStatementSource" with expression @[User::sqlCommand] (or whatever you named your variable).

Now run the task and it should work without a problem.

Comment: I am using OLE DB my query is of the form 

INSERT INTO Table1 (DateCol,OtherCol,OtherCol1....)
SELECT ?,SourceCol1,SourceCol2.... FROM sourceTable

ResultSet is none and parameter mapping has one item 
User::RecordDate, Input, DATE, 0

Comment: Thanks cairnz, when I set EvaluateAsExpression to true then click in expression nothing happens and there is no expression window.  I am using Visual Studio 2005 Sp1

Comment: Got a vote so revisited and re-read. Yes you are right you can do it that way, however I would not recommend it as it hides logic that can be harder to find when your projects are left to other people. By having the sql statement in an expression you can evaluate this, and the SQL Task clearly illustrates that it's a dynamic SQL. Finding a ? somewhere in there obfuscates things, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the expression here: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Objective:
To update datetime field (date+time) in parameter in sql task editor of SSIS package.

Description:
Step01: Created a variable having datatype as string.
e.g: 
Variable name: ReconcileStartDateTime
Data Type: String

Step02: Assign value to a variable. create 'Execute SQL Task'
General:
SQL Command-> select cast(getdate() as nvarchar(100)) as StartDateTime
ResultSet-> Single Row
ByPassprepare-> True

Result set tab:
Result Name: StartDateTime
Variable Name: User::ReconcileStartDateTime

Step 03: Create Execute SQL Task and use query as below:
SqlStatement: Update OrderDetail set StartDate = cast(? as datetime) where ID= 101;
Parameter mapping: click ADD button, set variable name User::ReconcileStartDateTime; Datatype as Nvarchar; Parameter to 0

Result: When execute the SSIS package, datetime is set accordingly. SQL Profile would help to see the output.
```